# Get File Size - Server Side Validation

Tags: html, google-apps-script, server-side, forms

I am trying to do server side validation of a form with a file attachment.  I cannot figure out the correct syntax for getting the file size.  I have tried:

```
form.myFile.files[0].size;
form.myFile.file.size;
form.myFile.getSize();

form.myFile.getName(); // this works and does return the name of the file.
```

---

It's just an html form that is submitted to a *.gs page. `<input type="file" id="myFile">` Then, on the *.gs page - doGet() - then pulls in the form.

---

Any ideas?  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: What is the data data type of `form` and `form.myFile`? Also, please add a [mcve].

Comment: It's just an html form that is submitted to a *.gs page.  <input type="file" id="myFile">  Then, on the *.gs page - doGet() - then pulls in the form and you can check the file size in bytes by using form.myFile.length; I changed it from bytes to kilobytes to megabytes by dividing it twice by 1024.  var fileSizeInMB = form.myFile.length/1024/1024;

Answer (score 0):

```
form.myFile.length; // that worked!
```

Comment: This will return the size of the file in bytes.  I need to check to make sure that the file is not over 2MB.  So, I just find the size in bytes...divide it by 1024 twice...then do a simple if(fileSize <= 2){return true;}else{return false;}